# Return eventmachine output to object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

In the below function (which is defined inside a class `Myclass`) I can run the function in ruby like

```
myoutput =  Myclass.get_par("http://eol.org/api/ping/1.0.json,http://eol.org/api/ping/1.0.json")
```

and the output of the calls gets printed to the terminal, but I the output is **not** assigned to the object `myoutput`.

is there a way to make the output return to an object, and not just print?

```
def self.get_par(urls)
  allurls = urls.split(',')
  results = []
  EM.synchrony do
    concurrency = 2
    results << EM::Synchrony::Iterator.new(allurls, concurrency).map do |url, iter|
      http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).aget
      http.callback { iter.return(http.response) }
      http.errback { iter.return(http) }
    end
    EventMachine.stop
    puts results # all completed requests
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`puts` returns `nil`, so returning the results of `puts` won't do much for you.

Return `results` instead, or do both, e.g.,

```
def self.get_par(urls)
  # ... etc ...
  puts results
  results
end
```

Comment: Thanks, figured out that I was returning the output in the wrong place. see above

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just returning the output in the wrong place

```
def self.get_par(urls)
  allurls = urls.split(',')
  results = []
  EM.synchrony do
    concurrency = 2
    results << EM::Synchrony::Iterator.new(allurls, concurrency).map do |url, iter|
      http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).aget
      http.callback { iter.return(http.response) }
      http.errback { iter.return(http) }
    end
    EventMachine.stop
  end
  results # SHOULD HAVE BEEN HERE #
end
```